# Matlab plot colours are dull

Tags: matlab, plot, export, figure, colorbar

I am trying to export some matlab figures with the export_fig script and so far everything went smoothly. But suddenly when I open a new figure and open the plot in there the colours become dull and pale instead of colourful as before.

Does anyone know why or can help?[image]

Also the ticks on the colourbar are different now. Less ticks and the top one, indicating 0 is not shown at all.

Comment: Could you show the code for this?

Comment: unfortunately not. Its a huge gui environment written from my institute. Sometimes it works and some other times it just messes up the colouring

Comment: Can you tell your specific parameters for the export_fig function? I think this might be due to compression or colour format change(RGB to CMYK), can you also try to output in bitmap and tif and see if there are any differences in the compression?

Comment: At least show the code which call the `export_fig` ... and if you can save the figure as a `.fig` file, upload it and give the link it would help people answering.